# What is the default value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: path, libraries, defaults, ld

In my case, it seems as if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set to the empty string. But all standard system tools still work fine, so I guess the dynamic linker checks for that case and uses some default for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in that case.

What is that default value? I guess it at least includes `/usr/lib` but what else? Is there any good systematic way in figuring out the standard locations where the dynamic linker would search?

This question is slightly different from what paths the dynamic linker will search in. Having a default value means, that it will use the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if given, or if not given, it will use the default value - which means, it will not use the default value if `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is provided.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The usual dynamic linker on Linux uses a cache to find its libraries. The cache is stored in `/etc/ld.so.cache`, and is updated by `ldconfig` which looks on the paths it’s given in `/etc/ld.so.conf` (and nowadays typically files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`). Its contents can be listed by running `ldconfig -p`.

So there is no default value for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, default library lookup doesn’t need it at all. If `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is defined, then it is used first, but doesn’t disable the other lookups (which also include a few default directories).

The [`ld.so(8)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) has the details:

> If a shared object dependency does not contain a slash, then it is
> searched for in the following order:
>
> - Using the directories specified in the `DT_RPATH` dynamic section
>   attribute of the binary if present and `DT_RUNPATH` attribute does
>   not exist.  Use of `DT_RPATH` is deprecated.
> - Using the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, unless the
>   executable is being run in secure-execution mode (see below), in
>   which case it is ignored.
> - Using the directories specified in the `DT_RUNPATH` dynamic section
>   attribute of the binary if present.
> - From the cache file `/etc/ld.so.cache`, which contains a compiled
>   list of candidate shared objects previously found in the augmented
>   library path.  If, however, the binary was linked with the `-z nodeflib` linker option, shared objects in the default paths are
>   skipped.  Shared objects installed in hardware capability
>   directories (see below) are preferred to other shared objects.
> - In the default path `/lib`, and then `/usr/lib`.  (On some 64-bit
>   architectures, the default paths for 64-bit shared objects are
>   `/lib64`, and then `/usr/lib64`.)  If the binary was linked with the
>   `-z nodeflib` linker option, this step is skipped.

If `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set or is empty, it [is ignored](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=elf/dl-load.c;h=c1b6d4ba0f133409c749944fea989ea89822560d;hb=HEAD#l801). If it is set to empty *values* (with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:` for example), those empty values are [interpreted as the current directory](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=elf/dl-load.c;h=c1b6d4ba0f133409c749944fea989ea89822560d;hb=HEAD#l446).