# How do library files (*.so) resolve shared dependencies?

Tags: libraries, dependencies, dynamic-linking, shared-library

If I invoke the following command:

```
ldd mylib.so
```

this then yields something along the lines of:

```
libopencv_features2d.so.4.1 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.4.1 (0x00007f83dee6b000)
```

If I copy `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.4.1` into my current working directory, I would then expect ldd to show `=> ./libopencv_features2d.so.4.1 (0x00007f83dee6b000)`

Instead, it still resolves it to `/usr/local/lib`. Why is that? And how do system dependencies like this get resolved? Is there also a way to influence the way dependencies are resolved? Can I force it to resolve it to my local directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dynamic linker looks for libraries in a variety of places, but those don’t include the current directory by default. On Linux, [the list is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/354296/86440)

- the paths defined in the binary’s rpath, if any;
- the paths listed in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, if any;
- the paths defined in the binary’s runpath, if any;
- the libraries known in `/etc/ld.so.cache`;
- the system’s library paths (`/usr/lib` etc.).

The link above provides more detail.

You can influence the way dependencies are resolved by exporting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`; specifically in your case:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
```

(Don’t leave it set to that value.)