# When building/running a program, how do to tell the dynamic linker where to find the appropriate libraries?

Tags: gcc, libraries, dynamic-linking

I am trying to install and run the program [Dsuite](https://github.com/millanek/Dsuite). To do so, I had to install a newer version of gcc locally (as I do not have root/super user privileges.) I did this with the following commands.

```
cd /scratch/wdavis/Tools/source/gcc-4.9.4/

./contrib/download_prerequisites

cd /scratch/wdavis/Tools/gcc/

/scratch/wdavis/Tools/source/gcc-4.9.4/configure --prefix /scratch/wdavis/Tools/local/ --disable-multilib

make bootstrap-lean

make install
```

Everything seemed to work. Then I started on DSuite.

```
git clone https://github.com/millanek/Dsuite.git

cd Dsuite/

cd utils/

python3 setup.py install --user --prefix=

cd ../
```

I had to edit the Makefile to tell it where to find the correct version of g++ (`/scratch/wdavis/Tools/local/bin/g++`). Then I called `make`. Everything seemed to work. However, DSuite gave the following error:

`Dsuite: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version` GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by Dsuite)`

I found two answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557919/what-is-libstdc-so-6-and-glibcxx-3-4-20) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542757/how-do-library-files-so-resolve-shared-dependencies) that suggested "You can try building with `-L/usr/local/lib64`, and running with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64` (if necessary).

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/scratch/wdavis/Tools/local/lib64/` Let me run Dsuite. However, `make -L/scratch/wdavis/Tools/local/lib64/` did not work, i.e., Dsuite gave the same error after rebuilding it.

My questions then are:

1. How to build a program such that when it is run, the dynamic linker will look in the correct directory for the libraries?
2. What would happen if I run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/scratch/wdavis/Tools/local/lib64/`, set up Dsuite to run, and then go on to run other programs without resetting LD_LIBRARY_PATH?
3. How do I reset LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To add a 4th question:
In the future, how would I avoid this problem?

Comment: For those who stumble upon this in the future, a work around for the error without setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH for everything is to set a new `screen` then `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/scratch/wdavis/Tools/local/lib64/` then leave `screen -r`. Dsuite will run with no problem and one is able to run other programs without worry they'll get hung up on the new LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 1):

1. 

`make -L/scratch/wdavis/Tools/local/lib64/` is wrong.

`-L` is a flag for GCC and linker (e.g. `ld`), not make.

You should export this via export CFLAGS or CXXFLAGS depending on the language of the app. And maybe export it via LDFLAGS - it all depends how the app is built and linked, you can use GCC or ld to compile the final binary/library.

E.g.

```bsh
export CFLAGS="-L/scratch/wdavis/Tools/local/lib64/"
export CXXFLAGS="-L/scratch/wdavis/Tools/local/lib64/"
export LDFLAGS="-L/scratch/wdavis/Tools/local/lib64/"
./configure && make
```

2. 

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a flag for glibc and it's meant for **executing** apps, not linking them.

Please read the docs carefully. It's all in there, `man gcc`, `man ld`, `man ld.so`

3. `man bash`

You do `unset VAR_NAME`

Comment: 1. ```export CFLAGS="-L/scratch/wdavis/Tools/local/lib64/"
export CXXFLAGS="-L/scratch/wdavis/Tools/local/lib64/"
export LDFLAGS="-L/scratch/wdavis/Tools/local/lib64/"
```
nor setting `-L/scratch/wdavis/Tools/local/lib64/` in the Makefile changed anything. Dsuite throws the same error. 

2. Yes? I'm trying to get Dsuite to execute without an error. 

3. Thanks!