# Accidentally over-wrote LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: bash, path

I'm operating Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2, and a little new to the bash syntax.

I overwrote the LD_LIBRARY_PATH when following a set of CUDA installation instructions, which specified to update as follows:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.5/lib64\
                         ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

The value LD_LIBRARY_PATH now only contains the specified path /usr/local/cuda-11.5/lib64\ and no other paths, so I'm wondering if I accidentally overwrote the old path (because of the carriage return in the middle?) instead of appending to it.

There are two possibilities:

1. The path was empty to start with, so nothing was overwritten, and no action required. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/354296) seems to indicate that it's originally empty, but running `strings /etc/ld.so.cache` as one of the comments suggest returns a long list.
2. The path wasn't empty, in which case I'd like to restore it.

Comment: Welcome to SO (well, SE!). Starting a new bash session should be good enough... let me explain a little bit more: running an `export` on bash only affects _that_ bash session. So, if you start a new bash session, the variable will be set to the original value that it had. Only _that_ specific bash where you ran the `export` is affected.

Comment: BTW, breaking the command between lines like this will cause trouble. In this case, the old & new parts of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` must be directly adjacent, with no spaces or line breaks in between. In shell syntax, things like spaces are important delimiters, and adding or removing them can change the meaning of a command completely.

Comment: @eftshift0 make that an answer and you'll get a +1 from me

Comment: @gordondavisson make that an answer and you'll get a +1 from me

Comment: Thank you both, very clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer you're linking to is correct. As it says, `ld` uses a cache to keep track of installed libraries.

As the answer goes on to explain, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty by default and is only one part of how `ld` looks up libraries.

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is useful for situations such as when you need to override which library `ld` picks or if the library isn't even in the cache (e.g., if you're developing a shared library and haven't installed it and updated the cache). Also, as already mentioned in the comments, formatting of this environment variable matters and you should be careful not to introduce any unintended characters.

While a default installation doesn't set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, you may have set it in a shell startup script, and in that case you can either re-source the script (if you're overwriting and not amending the path) or simply start a new shell. If you're not doing anything with the variable by default, a simple `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will do.

Lastly, there's no conflict between an empty `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and non-empty return from `strings /etc/ld.so.cache`.

Comment: You can see the origins of the cache with `cat /etc/ld.so.conf{,.d/*}`

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can get (most of the time) the original value of an environment variable on Linux with:

```
grep -z ^LD_LIBRARY_PATH= /proc/$$/environ | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Replace `$$` with some other pid than the shell's and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with some other environment variable as needed.

The process could've of course just overwritten it; but both the `ENVVAR=foo` in the shell and `setenv(3)` in the C library are just allocating a new string somewhere else.

---

On a regular system, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is supposed to be empty, and only be set by wrapper scripts and similar.